# radio group + javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a few radio buttons, after selection, to post the value to another page for processing, the scripts are as follow:-

```
<script>
function add_new_event(){
$.post('process.php',{

        event_color:document.getElementById('event_color').value,

}
</script>

        <input type="radio" name="event_color" id="event_color" value="#FF0000"> Color A
        <input type="radio" name="event_color" id="event_color" value="#FF6666"> Color B
        <input type="radio" name="event_color" id="event_color" value="#66FF99"> Color C
        <input type="radio" name="event_color" id="event_color" value="#CCFF66"> Color D
        <input type="radio" name="event_color" id="event_color" value="#00CCFF"> Color E
        <input type="radio" name="event_color" id="event_color" value="#996633"> Color F
```

and I am not successful. Is there anything wrong to the codes?? Thanks!

Comment: Besides the id problem you've missed the closing `})` on your `$.post(...` call.

Answer (score 1):

An ID should be unique, you are targeting all the elements as they all have the same ID, expecting to get something back.

You can target the elements by name or class instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        function add_new_event(){
            var myValue = $('[name="event_color"]').filter(':checked').val();
            $.post('process.php',{ event_color : myValue });
        }
    });
</script>
```

html :

```
    <input type="radio" name="event_color" value="#FF0000"> Color A
    <input type="radio" name="event_color" value="#FF6666"> Color B
    <input type="radio" name="event_color" value="#66FF99"> Color C
    <input type="radio" name="event_color" value="#CCFF66"> Color D
    <input type="radio" name="event_color" value="#00CCFF"> Color E
    <input type="radio" name="event_color" value="#996633"> Color F​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vz2Du/)

Comment: `add_new_event()` still needs to be called from somewhere (though you did so in your fiddle).

Answer (score 0):

assign same class to all radio button and then use this

```
$('.ClassName:checked').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery for that?

$("input[type=radio][name=event_color]:checked")